# Packaging a Wordpress Theme made with Roots (Sage)

Tags: node.js, wordpress, git, bower

I am just getting into the GIT / GULP / Bower workflow. I am basically a complete noob. I have a WordPresstheme being developed on my local machine via MAMP.
Say I wanted to package it up and open it on another Machine, either with Mamp or Wamp.

I don't think I can zip the theme folder with all the NPM Nodules, so what would be the best steps to take to avoid any or minimal bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using git you need to commit and push your changes to a remote repo. Then pull the repo down to the second machine and re-run the build process. 
In roots sage 8 that will mean:

1. Installing bower and npm globally (if you haven't already done so)
2. Installing the bower npm packages for you project
3. Running the gulp build task

In Sage the npm modules, bower packages and dist folders are ignored by git because they are listed in .gitignore. 
In general it's usually considered good practice NOT to commit any dependancies to your projects repo.